# Restriction of a quotient map to the unit ball in Banach spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$. The quotient map $\pi:X\rightarrow X/Y$ is open and $\pi(B_X)=B_{X/Y}$, where $B_X$ and $B_{X/Y}$ are the closed unit balls of $X$ and $X/Y$ respectively. Is it true that $\tilde{\pi}:B_X\rightarrow B_{X/Y}$, where $\tilde{\pi}$ is the restriction of $\pi$ to $B_X$, is still an open map with respect to the subspace topologies of $B_X$ and $B_{X/Y}$? In general, restrictions of open maps in topological spaces need not be open, but I wonder whether it can hold in this particular case.

Comment: But $\pi$ in not open, it's closed, think for example to $\pi^{-1}(\pi(B_X))=B_X\cup Y$, that isn't open, unless $Y=\{0\}$.

Comment: @G.Ottaviano $\pi$ is open for at least two reasons: it is a quotient map and it is a linear, continuous and onto map between Banach spaces, so the open mapping theorem applies. $\pi^{-1}(\pi(B_X))$ is actually equal to $B_X+Y$, but I don't see why I should conclude that $\pi$ is not open (which is false anyway). It is also false that $\pi$ is closed, even in finite dimension.

Comment: Oh, so $Y$ is a LINEAR subspace and the quotient isn't the collapse to a point of $Y$! In this case you are right. I have to think to your question then.